# Regex python guide

Tags: python, regex

I'm working with the arch package names. I am trying to extract split the name and version info, already removed the arch and extension.

So far I have the following:

```
(.*\D)-(.*)
```

and my sample data:

```
webkit2gtk-4.1-docs-2.42.5-1
webkit2gtk-4.1-2.42.5-1
libyuv-r2426+464c51a0-1
networkmanager-qt5-5.113.0-1
portaudio-1:19.7.0-2
purpose5-5.113.0-1
python-urllib3-1.26.18-1
ttf-meslo-nerd-font-powerlevel10k-20230403-2
volume_key-0.3.12-8
```

expected output would be 2 groups

```
networkmanager-qt5 <- package name
5.113.0-1 <- version and release together is fine
```

space separated the groups:

```
webkit2gtk-4.1-docs  2.42.5-1
webkit2gtk-4.1  2.42.5-1
libyuv  r2426+464c51a0-1
networkmanager-qt5  5.113.0-1
portaudio  1:19.7.0-2
purpose5  5.113.0-1
python-urllib3  1.26.18-1
ttf-meslo-nerd-font-powerlevel10k  20230403-2
volume_key  0.3.12-8
```

The format is `[package name]-[version]-[release]`

Can anyone help with a reliable solution?

Edit:
I think I was overthinking! The following works!

```
(.*)-(.*-.*)
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show, for each input example, what you want as output. Also explain what you current regex does not do.

Comment: In addition to showing the desired result for each example string please state the rule for determining where the name ends and the version begins.

Comment: updated the post. Hope that's more clear.

Comment: Gosh, ive just figured it out!
(.*)-(.*-.*)

Comment: I assume you are referring to [Arch Linux packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_package_guidelines), in which case you can split the string on `-(?=[^-]*-[^-]*$)`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5IKOz1/1)

Comment: In my comment above `(?= .... )` is a *positive lookahead*. It must be satisfied but is not part of the match returned. Only the penultimate hyphen is matched.

Comment: I believe your edit has clarified the question. It will be reopened if 5 votes to reopen are cast.

Comment: BTW, `r2426+464c51a0` and `1:19` are not a valid release numbers. `+` and `:` are not allowed according to the [docs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_package_guidelines#Package_versioning).

Comment: To match each of the last two hyphens, to split the string into three pieces (name, version and release), match -(?=[^-]*-?[^-]*$)`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/76sGjQ/1)

Comment: @deceze, closing the question for lack of details or clarity only 10 minutes after it was posted, and after two comments had asked for clarification, gave the OP insufficient time to respond to those comments, which the OP has now done. Please reconsider your action.

Comment: @Cary https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260263/476

Comment: @deceze, you've left the question closed after the OP's edit so I presume you still believe it "needs details or clarity".

Comment: @Cary OP has already figured it out. Does this still need an answer…?

Comment: Gibbz, you have an answer that works. If you are not interested in other answers (such as ones that split the string on a particular hyphen as opposed to using capture group) you should delete your question; else leave it and if it is reopened remove your answer from your question and post it as answer. (Questions and answers should be kept separate. Askers often post answers.) If you do post an answer you might explain that it works because `.*` is greedy, forcing the hyphens to match the last two hyphens in the string.

Comment: You could also make it more specific. matching at least a digit in the second part and digits in the third part `^(\S+)-([^\s\d-]*\d[^\s-]*-\d+)$` https://regex101.com/r/OhayG2/1

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Arch package guidelines](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_package_guidelines#Package_versioning), package versions and package releases may not contain hyphens, so you should just locate the last two hyphens to make the split:

```
(.*)-(.*)-(.*)
```

This will match in capture groups the package name (which *may* have hyphens), the package version and the package release. As `.*` is greedy, the first group will be as large as possible, so assuring that the split will be on the last two hyphens.

#### Other remarks

Note that the [same guidelines](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_package_guidelines#Package_versioning) also state that package versions may contain *"Letters, numbers, and periods only."* and that *"Package release tags follow the same naming restrictions as version tags."*

If we apply this to your input example, then we see that the following two violate those constraints:

- `libyuv-r2426+464c51a0-1`: `+` is an invalid character for a package version.
- `portaudio-1:19.7.0-2`: `:` is an invalid character for a package version.

So although the above regex splits the input string into parts, it doesn't assert whether inputs are actually in line with the rules.